# Python cannot access my usb device - insufficient permission

Tags: python-3.x, linux, visual-studio-code, ubuntu-18.04

Python script cannot send print to my usb Epson receipt printer

I am new to Ubuntu. I am trying to send some text to a thermal label printer connected to my computer via usb. Upon executing the code in Visual Studio Code by pressing the F5 key, I get the below error

```
File "/home/hdadmin/Documents/Python/POS/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/usb/backend/libusb1.py", line 595, in _check
raise USBError(_strerror(ret), ret, _libusb_errno[ret])
usb.core.USBError: [Errno 13] Access denied (insufficient permissions)
```

However, if I execute the same code with:

```
sudo python3 -m test5.py
```

then, it prints out all right. I have done many google searches, and it seems that this is a problem related to my rule settings, so I made the following rule in /etc/udev/rules.d/printerRule.rules

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1208", ATTRS{idProduct}=="3605",  MODE="0666", OWNER="hdadmin"
```

Still the problem persists.

The reason why I need to solve this problem is, I later need to compile the Python script using pyinstaller. If I compile as it is right now with

```
pyinstaller --onefile test5.py
```

The compile process will be fine, but I will still not be allowed to use the usb device when running the compiled file. Below is the full error report

```
(env) (base) hdadmin@HiddenDimsum:~/Documents/Python/POS$ cd /home/hdadmin/Documents/Python/POS ; env PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8 PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 /home/hdadmin/Documents/Python/POS/env/bin/python3.6 /home/hdadmin/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.9.34911/pythonFiles/ptvsd_launcher.py --default --client --host localhost --port 42379 /home/hdadmin/Documents/Python/POS/test4.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hdadmin/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.9.34911/pythonFiles/ptvsd_launcher.py", line 43, in <module>
    main(ptvsdArgs)
  File "/home/hdadmin/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.9.34911/pythonFiles/lib/python/ptvsd/__main__.py", line 432, in main
    run()
  File "/home/hdadmin/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.9.34911/pythonFiles/lib/python/ptvsd/__main__.py", line 316, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name='__main__')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/hdadmin/Documents/Python/POS/test4.py", line 2, in <module>
    printer = Usb(1208, 3605)
  File "/home/hdadmin/Documents/Python/POS/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/escpos/printer.py", line 51, in __init__
    self.open()
  File "/home/hdadmin/Documents/Python/POS/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/escpos/printer.py", line 62, in open
    check_driver = self.device.is_kernel_driver_active(0)
  File "/home/hdadmin/Documents/Python/POS/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/usb/core.py", line 1061, in is_kernel_driver_active
    self._ctx.managed_open()
  File "/home/hdadmin/Documents/Python/POS/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/usb/core.py", line 102, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/hdadmin/Documents/Python/POS/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/usb/core.py", line 120, in managed_open
    self.handle = self.backend.open_device(self.dev)
  File "/home/hdadmin/Documents/Python/POS/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/usb/backend/libusb1.py", line 786, in open_device
    return _DeviceHandle(dev)
  File "/home/hdadmin/Documents/Python/POS/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/usb/backend/libusb1.py", line 643, in __init__
    _check(_lib.libusb_open(self.devid, byref(self.handle)))
  File "/home/hdadmin/Documents/Python/POS/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/usb/backend/libusb1.py", line 595, in _check
    raise USBError(_strerror(ret), ret, _libusb_errno[ret])
usb.core.USBError: [Errno 13] Access denied (insufficient permissions)
```

Since I am new to Linux and Ubuntu, I need help and advices so that I can get permission to the usb devices connected to my computer. The expected outcome is, I should be able to run the test5.py by without the need for

sudo python3 -m test5.py

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/17540/how-do-i-set-executable-permissions-on-a-removable-drive Did you have a look at this? http://ask.xmodulo.com/change-usb-device-permission-linux.html or this? I trust you've made sure that the values for `idVendor` and `idProduct` are right, but did you restart your machine/reloaded the udev rules & re-plugged the usb as well?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to gst. You are fully right. My mistake is during my .rule creation

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1208", ATTRS{idProduct}=="3605",  MODE="0666",   OWNER="hdadmin"
```

Instead it should look as below, where GROUP="users". I misread the "users" and substituted it with the user name. I changed my rule to as below:

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1fc9", ATTRS{idProduct}=="2016", GROUP="users", MODE="0666"
```

and then in termial write

```
 $ sudo udevadm control --reload
```

and restarted the computer.